# How can I get the data whereas the data change with the time?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, real-time

Hello I get the data from a website using JSON in my android app. So I created an AsynsTask for this but the problem is actually I got the temperature of my house and this change and I don't want to push on a button to see the new temperature I want in real time the temperature which change. How can I do this ?

Here is my code :

```
inner class MyAsyncTask : AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){
    override fun onPreExecute() {

    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        try{
            test1.text = ""
            val url = URL(p0[0])
            val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnect.connectTimeout = 7000
            var inString = ConvertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
            publishProgress(inString)
        }catch(ex:Exception){}
        return " "

    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        try{
            var json = JSONArray(values[0])
            var temperature = json.getString(0)
            test1.text = "Temperature :"+temperature
            }catch(ex:Exception){}
    }
    override  fun onPostExecute(result: String?){}

}

fun ConvertStreamToString(inputStream:InputStream):String{
    val bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
    var line:String
    var AllString:String = ""
    try{
        do{
            line = bufferReader.readLine()
            if(line!=null){
                AllString+=line
            }
        }while(line!=null)
        inputStream.close()
    }catch(ex:Exception){}
    return AllString
}
```

So how can I do this to have in real time the temperature ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Did you consider using a service like `Firestore` ?

Comment: No I don't use Firestore just a website where there are some data using JSON format

Comment: You should definitely consider using a service like Firestore that will send new data to your app whenever it’s available. Another less nice solution would be to fetch data every x minutes. A more complex solution would be to build a system like Firebase yourself